# Aggregate objects in DDD, is this a potential aggregate?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

I have two entities Question and QuestionLog. The question obviously represents a question, and the QuestionLog represent an entity that the user may report on a particular question. For instance, if the question is wrong, poor quality etc.

Now from what I have read aggregate objects  are the only objects that have repositories, and since a QuestionLog object should not be in my system if the question that it is attached to is removed I thought that Question would be the aggregate root.

Is this a scenario that it makes sense to do so?

And what if I want a list of QuestionLogs that the user has submitted? Would I then make a JPQL that retrieves all QuestionLog that the user has submitted, or does that break the way it is intended to be? Should I instead retrieve a list of Questions that has QuestionLogs attached to them by that particular user, and then loop through all the questions and display properties of each QuestionLog?

Because it must be allowed to use the QuestionLog object outside of the Question class? I am a little confused about the restrictions and the way it is ment to be.

Comment: Btw an aggregate is not an object, it's a collection (think of it as a cloud) of related objects.The aggregate root is the object 'representing' the aggregate for a specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Since `QuestionLog` doesn't have meaning without a corresponiding `Question`, you are right - it is not an aggregate root.

All actions to do with `QuestionLog` should go through the `Question` aggregate.

If you want a list of `QuestionLog` for a user, you need to define, on the `Question` aggregate a `GetQuestionLogsForUser(user aUser)` method. You don't *have* to get all questions for a user, but control access to `QuestionLog`s through the aggregate.

You can *use* the `QuestionLog` objects outside of the aggregate root, but any actions on it should be done via the aggregate root, in particular persistence concerns.

Comment: So in the getQuestionLogsForUser(User user) would you return a list of Questions or QuestionLogs for that particular user? And do you also say that if I want to update a QuestionLog object on a Question I need to say myQuestion.updateQuestionLog(...); ? But that I can use QuestionLog anywhere in the code as long as it goes into the repository through a question?

Comment: @Dude - I thought the naming of the function was clear. You return a collection of `QuestionLog`. And yes, if you with to update a `QuestionLog` you need to do it through the aggregate. Updates to it should go through the aggregate so the aggregate can conserve all invariants.

Comment: Should QuestionLog have a reference to Question too? Or is it sufficient that Questions refer to QuestionLogs?

Comment: @Dude - That's a modelling question that I can't answer. If you need to navigate from a `QuestionLog` back to a `Question` then probably you will need this. If not, you don't.

Comment: Alright, so it has nothing to do with the question. That is fair. Just wondered if there was any limitations. So the bottom line is that you can use entities that is part of the aggregate as normal (instantiate, return them from aggregate root methods etc) but all interaction with the repository must go through the aggregate root object. And all findings of objects that are part of the aggregate root that does not have a own repository is done through the aggregate root?

Comment: @Dude - I would say _any_ changes. One of the roles of the aggregate is to maintain the invariants, which may be difficult if you manipulate inner objects outside of it.

Comment: Btw: I see now that this does not answer my question. How would you list all QuestionLogs that were added in the past 24 hours for instance? How would that method on Question work then? Would you have to make a JPQL that gives you all questions that added QuestionLog in the past 24 hour, and then in the repository loop through each question to accumulate a list of all the logs? This is what confuses me about aggregate objects.

Comment: @Dude - You would have to have a method on the `Question` aggregate for "All QuestionLogs that were added in the past 24 hours". The point is that you don't have repository calls outside an aggregate.

Comment: But I don't understand how to do this when I want all questionlogs that were added in the system the last 24 hours, not only on one question.

Comment: @Dude - You can have a static method on the aggregate. This will not be tied to any specific `Question` instance.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Oded, all *behavior* associated with `QuestionLog` instances should go through the `Question` aggregate. However, for queries you have a bit more flexibility. You can have a method on the `Question` aggregate that returns `QuestionLog` instances appropriate for a given query, but sometimes, requirements may make this approach impractical. In this case, you can employ the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) and have a repository dedicated to retrieving question logs based on the question ID and some filter. This allows you to leverage the database for queries. While it is true, some of the logic associated with questions will "leak" outside of the aggregate, it is a fair trade-off, especially if all *behavior* is kept with the aggregate.

When considering aggregate boundaries, you can't completely forget about technical concerns. It may be that a `Question` is expected to have very large numbers of associated question logs. In this case, it is impractical to load the entire aggregate into memory for a query that returns a small subset. You can even consider making `QuestionLog` an aggregate itself. Take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) for an in depth discussion on this subject.